# Determining probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The probability of getting no contact is 0.59. If a contact is established the probability of selling a subscription is 0.15. Determine the probability that anyone call the marketer does not sell a subscription.

[image: The solution]

Where does the 1 comes from in the solution? (1 * 0.59)

Comment: I assume there is no subscription if there was no contact, i.e. $P(S^c|C^c)=1$.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the probability of contact is 0.95? Seems from the image that $P(C)=0.41$.

Comment: It appears that the probability of making contact is supposed to be $.41$ rather than $.95$.  That also explains where the $.41$ comes from.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed .59. I edited the post.

Comment: But from the graphic $.59$ seems to be the probability of *not* getting a contact.

Comment: Yes, that is right. How do they calculate : P(Sc|Cc)=1

Comment: It is an assumption, not a calculation, but it is a natural assumption to make.  If there was never a salesman who tried to sell you a newspaper subscription who contacted you then it stands to reason that you won't have bought a newspaper subscription.  It makes sense that the only way to actually purchase a subscription in this scenario is via a salesman.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you very much!